# how to get the sql result in below format

Tags: mysql, sql

I have data in mysql DB in below format and I am trying to fetch the result in the format mentioned

**I have Data in DB in below format:**

```
**name, stockTimeInterval, date, stockTime, stockOpen**
WIPRO, 5_min_stock_data, 2021-01-01 , 09:15:00, 385.05
WIPRO, 5_min_stock_data, 2021-01-01 , 09:20:00, 386.60
WIPRO, 5_min_stock_data, 2021-01-01 , 09:25:00, 387.45

WIPRO, 5_min_stock_data, 2021-02-01 , 09:15:00, 385.05
WIPRO, 5_min_stock_data, 2021-02-01 , 09:20:00, 386.60
WIPRO, 5_min_stock_data, 2021-02-01 , 09:25:00, 387.45

WIPRO, 5_min_stock_data, 2021-03-01 , 09:15:00, 385.05
WIPRO, 5_min_stock_data, 2021-03-01 , 09:20:00, 386.60
WIPRO, 5_min_stock_data, 2021-03-01 , 09:25:00, 387.45
```

**Question:
How to get the result in the format of:**

```
**name, stockTimeInterval, date, stockTime, stockOpen**
WIPRO, 5_min_stock_data, 2021-01-01 , 09:15:00, 385.05
WIPRO, 5_min_stock_data, 2021-02-01 , 09:15:00, 385.05
WIPRO, 5_min_stock_data, 2021-03-01 , 09:15:00, 385.05

WIPRO, 5_min_stock_data, 2021-01-01 , 09:20:00, 386.60
WIPRO, 5_min_stock_data, 2021-02-01 , 09:20:00, 386.60
WIPRO, 5_min_stock_data, 2021-03-01 , 09:20:00, 386.60

WIPRO, 5_min_stock_data, 2021-01-01 , 09:25:00, 387.45
WIPRO, 5_min_stock_data, 2021-02-01 , 09:25:00, 387.45
WIPRO, 5_min_stock_data, 2021-03-01 , 09:25:00, 387.45
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a two-tiered sort:

```sql
SELECT name, stockTimeInterval, date, stockTime, stockOpen
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY name, stockTimeInterval, stockTime, date;
```

Note that `stockTime` is coming *before* the `date`.  More typically, date and time are in a single datetime field, rather than in separate fields.